# A gap after the ''Search''

Tags: 14.04

Above the "Search" there is a gap. It says add icon there. I drag and drop an icon but there is still that gap. How can I fix this?

Screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4Gf7.jpg]

Comment: What happens when you right-click on it ?  It should give you a menu of some sort, is there a "remove" or "delete" option ?

Comment: @JonasCz when i right-click on that gap ,  nothing happens